# How to validate number using AdonisJS

Tags: node.js, validation, adonis.js

I'm working on project using AdonisJS 4.1, I have a problem with validating number, here is my code in my code in the controller

```
const validation = await validate(request.all(), {
    posts_per_page: required|number|min:0
})
```

When I tried to fill the form field with any number larger than 0, it always give error message as following:

```
number validation failed on posts_per_page
```

Any help on resolving this issue will be much appreciated, thanks before.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is that by default an HTML form will send all the fields as string. You need to sanitize them first [using the sanitizer](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/validator#_sanitizing_user_input):

```
const { sanitize } = use('Validator')

const data = sanitize(request.all(), {
  posts_per_page: 'to_int',
})
```

Then you will be able to use `data` instead of `request.all()` for your validation.

Also, take notes that you should use `request.only()` instead of `request.all()` for security reasons.

Comment: Hi same thing I am trying but it showing , SyntaxError
Unexpected token const validation = await validate(request.all(), rules). I am not able to know what the exact issue

Answer (score 1):

The `min` rule evaluates the value length (i.e. the length of a string or an array), not the value itself. You need to user the `above` rule for this. Try

```js
const validation = await validate(request.all(), {
    posts_per_page: 'required|number|above:0'
})
```

Comment: Exactly this. Also, "range" is another helpful option if you have an upper bound as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
const rules = {
  posts_per_page: 'required|number|min:0'
}

const validation = await validate(request.all(), rules)
```

Comment: Hi same thing I am trying but it showing , SyntaxError
Unexpected token const validation = await validate(request.all(), rules). I am not able to know what the exact issue